# Pandas: iterate and return: index, next index and row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe like so:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({0: [1, 4, 7, 10], 1: [5, 7, 9, 12], 2: ['v=55', 'g=40', 'd=84', 'f=31']})
s = pd.Series([0, 15, 30, 45])
df.set_index([s], inplace=True)
```

I want to iterate over the rows and get back:

- index [i],
- index [i+1],
- the number value split from column 2 eg(v=55 should give 55).

I have tried using iterrows, to get the 2 indexes and the row:

```py
ind=0
for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
  if index==0: #continue to start loop from second value
    continue
  splitvalue= row[2].split('=')[1]
  print ( ind, index, splitvalue) #print ind, next index, splitvalue
  ind=index #update ind with current index
```

However the like this the splitvalue it returns is the **next** one and not the current one

current answer:

```py
ind:0, index=15, splitvalue:'40' 
ind:15, index=30, splitvalue:'84'....
```

wanted answer:

```py
ind:0, index=15, splitvalue:'55'
ind:15, index=30, splitvalue:'40'....
```

Comment: What do you expect index[i+1] to be for the last row?

Comment: I simplified my question down too much. I am splitting a dataframe (df2) insto segments: df2.iloc[i:i+1]. and the rows of df are the tittles of the subdatarames. Therefore for the last one I just want i, and split df2[i:]

Comment: just curious, why do you want to loop over the rows? Depending on your answer, you may not need to loop. the point of pandas/dataframe is that you try to avoid doing so as much as possible.

Comment: The dataframe has a repeating sequence of 2 header rows, 50 rows of datavalues. I am trying to create a neew dataframe without the header rows. One cell of the header rows has the iteration number of the data, I want to put that in a column next to the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are getting the value for the row, you start printing at the second row, when you really want to start printing at the first row. You can use `df.loc[ind]` to get the row at `df.index == ind`.

```
ind=0
for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    if index==0: #continue to start loop from second value
        continue
    splitvalue = df.loc[ind][2].split('=')[1]
    print (f"ind:{ind}, index:{index}, splitvalue:{splitvalue}") #print ind, next index, splitvalue
    ind = index #update ind with current index
```

Let me know if that explanation makes sense.

Comment: Did this work for you? I'm not sure I understand your end goal from your comments.